# Legal implications of using corporate infrastruture in cyber attacks against Russia

Tags: hacking

Recently, our data centers have been migrated from Ukraine to central Europe. Instead of shutting down, we intend to dedicate the infrastructure to launching cyber attacks against Russian state services and state-related businesses. In particular, we wish to participate in forms of distributed attacks organized by [IT Army of Ukraine](https://twitter.com/FedorovMykhailo/status/1497642156076511233). What are the legal implications? Where can we receive official authorization? Note that the company is not settled in Ukraine. I'm looking for a rough overview to spark a discussion before consulting an actual lawyer.

Comment: This would constitute legal advice, we don't do that here. We most likely will reject the migration because of that. If you want to enlist your server infrastructure with a country, the relevant ministry would be the best start.

Comment: To add to the discussion, I dont think geopolitics is appropriate for this stackexchange.  Laws exist within a nation, written, passed and enforced.... they do not necessarily exist between nations except on the level of treaties between governments, which arent necessarily enforced on citizens. And certainly wartime complicates the matter of law on top of it. So frankly I dont think a discussion on laws passed by any society on this planet is applicable to a conversation on wartime tactics and actions between nations.

Comment: @Trish I imagine the relevant ministry begins with the host nation they're currently operating their infrastructure out of. To first seek permission from that nations government whether or not they want to host aggression on a neighboring nuclear power.  The relevant ministry of ukraine would be the second most relevant in this endeavor.